# Text line segmentation using OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to extract the text lines from the below figure and I tried the below code but I am getting only a single image without any data. While masking the images all the lines are masked perfectly. Below i attached the masked image, final output image and desired output image.

```
img = cv.imread('Handwritten_data/Ostu_images/H_1.jpg')

lower = (0, 0, 0)
upper = (0, 120, 150)

# threshold on border color
mask = cv.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# dilate threshold
kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (250,10))
mask = cv.morphologyEx(mask, cv.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# recolor border to white
img[mask==255] = (255,255,255)


# Inverting the mask by
# performing bitwise-not operation
mask_black = cv.bitwise_not(mask)
Mask = cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask_black)

gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# otsu threshold
thresh = cv.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_OTSU )[1] 

# apply morphology open
kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (250,10)) 
morph = cv.morphologyEx(thresh, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)


# creating a folder
try: 
    # creating a folder named data
    if not os.path.exists('Image_0'):
        os.makedirs('Image_0')
  
# if not created then raise error
except OSError:
    print ('Error: Creating directory of data')

# find contours and bounding boxes
bboxes = []
bboxes_img = img.copy()
contours = cv.findContours(morph, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for cntr in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(cntr)
    cv.rectangle(bboxes_img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0,0,255), 1)
    bboxes.append((x,y,w,h))

for j in range(len(bboxes)):
    (x,y,w,h) = bboxes[j]
    crop = img[y-10:y+h+10, x-10:x+w+10]
    cv.imwrite(f'Image_0/S_{j}.jpg', crop)
```

Any suggestions or help to solve this problem.[image]

Below is the masking image
[image]

final image ouput
[image]

desired image output be like
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing. Maybe you create list with only one item, or make other mistake.

Comment: you can use `os.makedirs('Image_0', exist_ok=True)` without checking `if not os.path.exists('Image_0'):`

Comment: maybe you should display image after every operation to see what you have on image. it seems you removed all text from image using `img[mask==255] = (255,255,255)`

Comment: it seems all lines are recognized but as single contour, not separated elements.

Comment: You explanations are perfectly opaque to me. "While masking the images all the lines are masked perfectly. But on execution, it is giving only a single image." ???

Comment: @furus after commenting this part `img[mask==255] = (255,255,255)`  it is throwing error as follows `error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:801: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'`

Comment: One issue you have is that most of the masked lines connect so that when you extract the contour bounding boxes, you will not get separated lines. You need to modify your morphology so that your masked regions are not touching. Make your morphology kernel only 1 or 2 pixels tall, not 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea you presented for text line segmentation is correct. But the approach needs some tweaking.

***Note:***

Whenever you want to mask a portion of the image, make sure the masked region is in white. Because when finding contours the algorithm looks for white regions. Since you were looking for contours that were in black the algorithm missed it.

The following is modified with the above idea.

***Solution:***

```
img = cv2.imread(image_file)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (150,2))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh2, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)
```

Below is the mask image:

[image]

```
bboxes = []
bboxes_img = img.copy()
contours = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for cntr in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    cv2.rectangle(bboxes_img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0,0,255), 1)
    bboxes.append((x,y,w,h))
```

The following is the final result with bounding boxes:

[image]

You can now add your portion of the code to save each region as a separate image file. You can try modifying the kernel parameters and exploring different morphological operations to get a better mask region.

Hope this puts you on the right track!

Comment: thank you for your time and suggestions for improvement of the code